# set name to window and reference to it with command

Tags: vim

I have 8 square (equal) windows in my vim screen spanning over 2 large monitors and I want to refer each of them with shortcuts < A-1 >, < A-2 > ... . There is a command in vim N-wincmd-wincmd that allows to to reference to the window by its number, but it is useless for me because other plugins sometimes create windows (like syntastic for syntax checking) and referring by number doesn't exactly matches the correct window. I thought maybe I could reference windows by names, so the question is, how do I set a name to some window, and then make a short cut so the cursor goes to the window with that name when pressing < A - n > where n is the window number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lets you save a static extra window number for each visible window, and then jump to it quickly.

Just call `:MarkWins` when your layout is clean, and then the mappings `<A-1>`, `<A-2>`... will jump to the good window, even if new windows were created after that.

```
" Mark all visible windows from 1 :
command! MarkWins call s:mark_windows()
" Go to a previously marked window :
command! -nargs=1 GoToMarkedWin call s:go_to_marked_win(<f-args>)

" Mappings (Alt-1, Alt-2...) :
for s:n in range(1,8)
    exe printf('noremap <silent> <a-%d> :GoToMarkedWin %d<cr>', s:n, s:n)
endfor

function! s:mark_windows()
    let l:old_winnr = winnr()
    windo let w:win_mark = winnr()
    exe printf('%d wincmd w', l:old_winnr)
endf

function! s:go_to_marked_win(n)
    let l:old_winnr = winnr()
    while 1
        if exists('w:win_mark') && w:win_mark == a:n
            return
        endif
        wincmd w
        if winnr() == l:old_winnr | return | endif
    endw
endf
```

Comment: thanks, but the script is not working. is there a way to show the error log? I type :MarkWin and seems that it loops forever because the "MarkWin" command stays on the command line and doesn't disappear.

Comment: It's strange; it works well for me, and i really don't see any reason for freezing in the `s:mark_windows()` function. Try to put some lines like `echo 'Line 13'` before each code line in the function, to check from your side where it freezes exactly

Comment: this is how I create windows, not sure if that matters:  :function Dev8()
    :vsplit
    :vsplit
    :vsplit
    :split
    :wincmd l
    :split
    :wincmd l
    :split
    :wincmd l
    :split
:endfunction

Comment: It works as well when I try your func.. What about the `echo` test? Yan can also try (for debug) to go on a wanted win, execute `let w:win_mark=2`, and then try to press Alt-2